# Multiple AzureAD Admins On Single Azure Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

Is it possible to have more than one admin on an Azure tenant? We have a federation with Microsoft and have provisioned our on-prem AD Admins to be global admins in Azure. What I see is, my original account is the admin, when I add a new account and login it tells me I need a subscription.

Am I missing something? Is there a check box we tick somewhere? Or do we just need to call Microsoft and let them know? Am I the only person to have tried this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add those "organisational" accounts as co-administrators via the Azure Management Portal.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg456328.aspx

Comment: So I don't have enough rep to mark this as answered or up vote it... :( but your response was in fact the answer. If someone with more rep than me could mark this as answered i'd appreciate it!